# Get int from textField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm new to cocoa.
I create project where I have one textField and one button.
I make function for button, where I start my other function and it's ok. But I need to take number value from textField as parameter for my function...like this:

```
@implementation AppController

- (IBAction)StartReconstruction:(id)sender {
    int RecLine = //here i need something like textField1.GetIntValue();
    drawGL(RecLine);
}
@end
```

In IB I only create number formated text field. But I don't know how to call it from code :(

thanks for help

Comment: Have you learned your Objective-C syntax yet? Pretty sure that `*` ain't supposed to be there. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you connected the textfield between your code and IB? You will need to define the ivar and property in your @interface declaration, like this:

```
@interface BlahBlah {
    UITextField *textField1;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;


...
@end
```

After you have declared your ivar and connected it to your text box in IB (search google to see how), you can simply call

```
[textField1.text intValue];
```

to get the integer value of the string in the textbox (mind you, this is quick and dirty and does not validate the input).

Comment: It's `NSTextField`, not `UITextField` he's asking about. Your code won't work with the former.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to get text value first. NSTextField inherits from NSControl which has intValue method, so...

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    int intVal = [textField intValue];
    NSLog (@"Int value is %i", intVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you created an IBOutlet for the textfield so you can connect it in Interface Builder?  If not, then you need to add a textfield instance to your header file and make it a synthesized property.  In your header:

```
@interface AppController
{
    NSTextField *myTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
```

And in your implementation:

```
@synthesize myTextField;
```

Then in IB, control-click drag from the textfield to "File's Owner".  A popup menu will appear and you should be able to connect it to "myTextField".

To get the int value, you should be able to do:

```
[myTextField.stringValue intValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
int RecLine = [textField1.text intValue];
```

This is assuming your textField1 has something that can be converted to an integer.

Comment: "textField1.text" works for UITextField, but not NSTextField.  Unless I'm mistaken, I think this is a Cocoa question, not Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score -1):

To use properties you will need to change your project's base SDK to OS X 10.5 or higher. Check this menu:

```
Project > Edit Project Settings > Build > Base SDK
```

[image]